# How to I remove L from Long field's values in java spring

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I put query param for my list services for example:

```
tablename/list?query=id:10
```

it is running but I added other param

```
'personTNo'
 tablename/list?query=id:10&personTNo=101035678
```

id is Integer but `personTNo` is Long
when I try to this sql returns `select * from TABLENAME WHERE personTNo=10L`

but this I want to return without 'L' for Long value. It is my code's a bit section in RepositoryCustom class

```java
    public List<TABLENAME> getTable(Specification aTablenameSpec) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = mEntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Object> query = builder.createQuery();
        Root<TABLENAME> root = query.from(TABLENAME.class);
        String queryWhere = null;
        org.hibernate.query.Query hibernateQuery = null;
        Predicate predicate = aTablenameSpec.toPredicate(root, query, builder);
        if (predicate != null) {
            query.where(predicate);
            query.select(root);
            TypedQuery<Object> typedQuery = mEntityManager.createQuery(query);
            hibernateQuery = typedQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class);
            String queryString = hibernateQuery.getQueryString();
```

This row returns with L result, How to remove 'L' value in sql

Comment: Can you edit the problem description to add clarity, explain any differences between the underlying types of id and personTNo, and possible include a bit more of the code?

Comment: edited id is person id and its type is Integer bu personTNo is Long value @Sean Mickey

Answer (score 0):

Use INTEGER() function in the sql query. You can also try CAST() or CONVERT() functions in the query

Answer (score 0):

Based on the problem description and code, it seems safe to assume the tech stack includes: `JPA` and `Spring Data JPA`.

And I understand that you want to remove the `Long` value `L` suffixes, but it's not clear if that's because the suffixes are causing a problem or exactly *why* you want the suffixes removed.

I only say that because the example query string appears to be a valid `JPA` query:

```
select * from TABLENAME WHERE personTNo = 10L
```

`JPA` support for the use of literal values in queries includes support for standard `Java` numeric (`integer`/`long`/`float`/`double`) literal value syntax.

Which means the `L` suffix on the literal `Long` value of `personTNo`, as defined in your query (`10L`), is legitimate, valid, and should not cause a problem.

Please let me know if I've missed the point, made an incorrect assumption, or overlooked something, and I will follow up.